# Microsoft Azure Face API returns "com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.rest.ClientException: Image size is too small."

Tags: android, azure, azure-analysis-services, face-api

When I send a photo to the Microsoft Azure Face API ([the api](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/face/), [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiinjavaforandroidtutorial#feedback)), I am receiving

> com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.rest.ClientException: Image size is too small.

But when I am debugging the application and when I inspect the following code

```
faceServiceClient.detect( params[0], false, false, expectedFaceAttributes )
```

actually it IS working and I CAN get the result, but only the first time. If I press "inspect" one more time I will again receiving the above mentioned error message.

P.S. I tried using different images and the behaviors is the same. I would appreciate any help.

The application:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bitmap bmpImage;
    TextView txtResult;

    ByteArrayInputStream bs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        Button btnMicrosoft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMicrosoft);

        btnMicrosoft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFaces();
                makeMicrosoftCall();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getFaces() {
        bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.face_1);

    }

    private void makeMicrosoftCall() {
        imgEncoding();
        GetEmotionCall emotionCall = new GetEmotionCall();
        emotionCall.execute(bs);

    }

    public void imgEncoding()
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmpImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }

    // asynchronous class which makes the api call in the background
    private class GetEmotionCall extends AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]> {
        GetEmotionCall() {
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            txtResult.setText("Getting results...");
        }

        // this function is called when the api call is made
        @Override
        protected Face[] doInBackground(InputStream... params) {
            FaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient("https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0", "*******************");

            // the only attribute wanted it emotional state
            FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[] expectedFaceAttributes = new FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[]{FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Emotion};

            try {
                //THE PROBLEMATIC AREA
                return faceServiceClient.detect( params[0], false, false, expectedFaceAttributes );      

            } catch (ClientException e) {
                Log.e("ClientException", e.toString());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm encountering the same issue, I think it is related to using InputStream

Comment: @FrancisPeters That was the same issues which i was facing for 2 hrs. finally when i placed img file in assets folder and open it directly into stream using `InputStream iStream = getAssets().open("img1.jpg")` then passed it to the detect function. it worked fine!